# Can I use Shell or Python realize calling a C programe and give all the parameter it requires?

Tags: python, shell, automation

I have met a problem and I have no knowledge that whether this can be realized in Shell like Bash or Python.

I need to run a C programe several times, the programe is "atompot" for TEM image simulation. If I run this programe

```
./atompot
```

its output like this:

```
atompot version dated 8-oct-2012 EJK
Copyright (C) 1998-2010 Earl J. Kirkland
This program is provided AS-IS with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
under the GNU general public license

calculate projected atomic potentials (to use in multislice)
using FFTW

Name of file with input crystal data :
```

Then I need to give the input crtstal data file like:

```
stra.dat
```

Then you can get:

```
Name of file to get binary output of atomic potential :
```

Then I give the name:

```
straa.tif
```

Then you get:

```
Real space dimensions in pixels Nx, Ny :
```

Your answer like :

```
512 512
```

Then the output like:

```
 Replicate unit cell by NCELLX,NCELLY,NCELLZ :
```

answer:

```
  8 8 8
```

Ask:

```
  Do you want to add thermal displacements to atomic coord.? (y/n) :
```

answer:

```
  n
```

The proceduess is somewhat like this.
Can I use Shell or Python realize calling a C programe and give all the parameter it requires to make the programe run automatically?

For example I can change the unit cell form 8 8 8 to 100 100 100.
And keep other parameter the same. It seems that all this can be done in a Sheel script but How to realize some C programe that gives you instruction of what to input.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the program reads from stdin, just put everything in a file:

```
stra.dat
straa.tif
512 512
8 8 8
n
```

And the run:

```
./atompot < filename
```

If you want to do something more complex (ie parse the output or implement branching), you could look into subprocess.Popen in python.

Comment: YEP!Thanks for your advises. That's really useful!

Answer (score 1):

You can make a shell script like this:

```
echo -e 'stra.dat\nstraa.tif\n...' | ./atompot
```

For more control, you might want to take look at [`expect`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).